# Как программно вернуться на предыдущий модальный экран?

Tags: ios, navigationcontroller

Как программно вернуться на предыдущий модальный экран, у которого нет (соответственно, у него не должен отображаться UINavigationBar) UINavigationController? (см. прикрепленный скрин)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

0   В контроллере на который хотите вернуться пропишите:

```
@IBAction func someUnwindFunc(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) { //Название по Вашему вкусу
    print("unwinded")
}
```

1. В  `storyboard` от элемента, по нажатию на который хотите вернуться протяните:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. и выберите нужное:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. В случае, если хотите программно, то протяните от Вашего контроллера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выберите эту `segue` и задайте идентификатор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем в нужном месте в коде:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "SomeIdentifier", sender: nil)
```

Это 2 основных способа.

Comment: а чем это отличается от если я просто протяну от третьего vc к первому (считаем слева направо на скрине в вопросе) segue и потом вызову этот переход performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:), при определенном событии в третьем vc. Да, переход будет, но певый vc теперь будет иметь navbar, которого у него раньше не было ..